# Understanding MinConflicts algorithm

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence, heuristics, constraint-satisfaction

In wikipedia it is written ([Min-conflicts algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-conflicts_algorithm)):

> ```
> value <-- the value v for var that minimizes CONFLICTS(var,v,current,csp)
> ```

but what does that mean?

For example if I have the following matrix for the N queen problem:

```
  0 1 2 3
0 Q - - -
1 - Q - -
2 - - Q -
3 - - - Q
```

Here we have 3 conflicts, right?

What would be the value of the CONFLICTS function if we move the queen on position 1,1 to position 2,3 getting:

```
  0 1 2 3
0 Q - - -
1 - - - -
2 - - Q -
3 - Q - Q
```

Should CONFLICTS return 2 or should it return 4? In other words should we count only the conflicts of this particular queen or should we count all conflicts  globally on the board.

Wikipedia also says

> The CONFLICTS function counts the number of constraints violated by a particular object, given that the state of the rest of the assignment is known

but this doesn't feel right.

Comment: Wikipedia also says "The CONFLICTS function counts the number of constraints violated by a particular object, given that the state of the rest of the assignment is known.". But this doesn't feel right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "The CONFLICTS function counts the number of constraints violated by a particular object, given that the state of the rest of the assignment is known" but this doesn't feel right.

It's right.

> ```
>   0 1 2 3
> 0 Q - - -
> 1 - Q - -
> 2 - - Q -
> 3 - - - Q
> ```
>
> Here we have 3 conflicts, right?

Here `CONFLICTED[csp]` is `[Q0, Q1, Q2, Q3]` (`Qn` means queen on `n`-th column). If the randomly chosen variable is `Q1`:

> ```
>   0 1 2 3
> 0 Q 1 - -
> 1 - Q - -
> 2 - 1 Q -
> 3 - 2 - Q
> ```

`Q1` breaks `3` constraints (it attacks `Q0`, `Q2`, `Q3`).

`CONFLICTS(Q1)` randomly returns `(0,1)` or `(2,1)` (if there is more than one value with a minimum number of conflicts, `CONFLICTS` chooses one randomly).

It does **not** return `(3,1)`.

> ```
>   0 1 2 3
> 0 Q 1 - -
> 1 - 3 - -
> 2 - 1 Q -
> 3 - Q - Q
> ```

`CONFLICTS(Q1)` randomly returns `(0,1)` or `(2,1)`.

`CONFLICTS(var, v, current, csp)` considers a particular queen (`var`) in the `current` state.

---

A possible evolution of the system is:

```
  0 1 2 3
0 Q 1 - -
1 - Q - -
2 - 1 Q -
3 - 2 - Q

CONFLICTED[csp] = [Q0, Q1, Q2, Q3];
var = Q1
value = (0, 1)
```

---

```
  0 1 2 3
0 Q Q - -
1 1 - - -
2 1 - Q -
3 1 - - Q

CONFLICTED[csp] = [Q0, Q1, Q2, Q3];
var = Q0
value = (1, 0)
```

---

```
  0 1 2 3
0 1 Q - -
1 Q - - -
2 1 - Q -
3 1 - - Q

CONFLICTED[csp] = [Q0, Q1, Q2, Q3];
var = Q0
value = (2, 0)
```

The same `var` (here `Q0`) can be selected multiple times if it remains in `CONFLICTED[csp]`.

---

```
  0 1 2 3
0 - Q 2 -
1 - - 1 -
2 Q - Q -
3 - - 1 Q

CONFLICTED[csp] = [Q0, Q2, Q3];
var = Q2
value = (3, 2)
```

---

```
  0 1 2 3
0 - Q - 1
1 - - - 0
2 Q - - 2
3 - - Q Q

CONFLICTED[csp] = [Q2, Q3];
var = Q3
value = (1, 3)
```

---

```
  0 1 2 3
0 - Q - -
1 - - - Q
2 Q - - -
3 - - Q -

CONFLICTED[csp] = [];

current_state is a solution of csp
```